# Data structures sharing between C++ and C#

Tags: c#, c++, header-files

I have an application written in C++ and running on PPC processor. The application reads a binary configuration file from its local storage.

The file structure is defined in a large set of structures - each defined in a different .h file (structures are packed using **attribute**((packed))

I need to create a PC application with which the user can fill this data, then it is stored into the binary configuration file (which is later uploaded to the target (PPC) via FTP commands and then stored in the target local storage for use).

Is there an option to use the predefined .h files in a c# application so will have a shared data structure (and not duplication of code...)???

Comment: No, you need to define data types in both C# and C++

Comment: so maybe is there an option to write a DLL with 1 function that gets all parameters as input parameters and gives an output parameter (pointer) to the data structure filled according to the h file structures? and C# will use it just as a binary buffer to write into a file?

Comment: You still need to know a layout of your data. Its pretty easy to do for POD structs. You just need to use `struct` and `StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)` attribute

Comment: Recompile your c++ library with .NET as described in this article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14180/Using-Unmanaged-C-Libraries-DLLs-in-NET-Applicatio